# R; Avoiding for loops

Tags: r, for-loop

Is there a way to avoid for-loop & if-else in R as used in the code below.

```
drive_type<-vector(mode="expression",length=length(my_file$xx))
for(i in 1:length(my_file$xx)){
    serial_num<-my_file$xx[i]
temp_1<-my_file[grep("serial_num",rownames(my_file)), ]
if('6' %in% temp_1$yy){
  drive_type[i]<-'12header'}
else {
  drive_type[i]<-'6header'}
}
```

Comment: You can use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` i.e. `with(my_file, ifelse(grepl("serial_num", rownames(my_file)) & yy==6, '12header', '6header'))`  or without any `ifelse`', `drive_type <- rep('6header', nrow(my_file)); drive_type[grepl("serial_num", rownames(my_file)) & my_file$yy==6] < '12header'`

Comment: `ifelse` has the added benefit of being vectorized, which, depending on the size of your data, should perform much faster.